# How to let a locally-emulated Firebase Function hit real remote Firestore?

Tags: firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

Due to there still being [no support for web client reads from locally-emulated firestore](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1001) at the moment, my best option for some parts of development is to allow the local functions to modify the real Firestore (in a separate dev project).

I tried the "Admin SDK configuration snippet", but it doesn't work, the reason I suppose being the mocked `firebase-admin`.

Has anyone documented doing this properly?